# td is ignoring width but height is honored

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to use css to set the width and height of a td. The height works fine, the width is ignored. I'm sure this is one of things where I'm going to smack myself when the answer is shown to me. I've checked the spelling, tried em and px but width just is ignored. Here's a link to a fiddle showing the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/kdubs/jBjr2/

the html

```
<div class="overall_theme">
<table id="disp_output">
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <th>Advantages</th>
    <td id="disp_ads">00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Disadvantages</th>
    <td id="disp_disads">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Total</th>
    <td id="disp_total">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>dbg</th>
    <td id="dbg_td">txt</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

and the css

```
.overall_theme table, .overall_theme tr, .overall_theme td, .overall_theme th {
  text-align:center;
  border-collapse:collapse;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width:2em;
}
.overall_theme table {
  background-color:cornflowerblue;
  margin-top:.5em;
  margin-bottom:.5em;
}
.overall_theme > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(odd), .overall_theme th:nth-   child(odd) {
background-color:#00cc00;
}
#disp_output td {
  width:30em;
  height:35px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of reasons:

Your first rule is more specific than the last rule. Try making the last rule more specific:

```
.overall_theme #disp_output td {
  width:30em;
  height:35px;
}
```

For more details on specificity, see: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Secondly, the width of `#disp_output td` is significantly larger than `.overall_theme table`. With the content in column 1, the table is already greater than 2em.

If you make `.overall_theme table` larger, you will in turn be able to see tweaks made to the width of `#disp_output td`.

Consider splitting up the CSS rules for the widths of `.overall_theme table, .overall_theme tr, .overall_theme td, .overall_theme th` or use `min-width` to achieve what I think you are trying to achieve.

Comment: gah... that was it. thanks for the other tips also.  what was confusing me was the Chrome debugger had the width line with the 2em, crossed out and the line with the 30em left alone, so it looked like it was trying to use the 30em.